# Google Maps URL returning route from GPS location to specific point

Tags: google-maps, url, browser, geolocation

is it possible to generate URL link which redirect to google maps and set route dynamically from allowed GPS location to specific address?

for example someone from point A want to get to point B - URL redirecting to google maps with route from A to B.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, solved it. URL just need to have a pattern

> https://maps.google.com/maps?directionsmode=driving&dirflg=d&daddr=
>   INSERT LATITUDE+INSERT LONGITUDE&hl=LANGUAGE CODE

for example:

> https://maps.google.com/maps?directionsmode=driving&dirflg=d&daddr=52.799022+18.899743&hl=pl

note that user need to ignore "from" input after redirection and just confirm to get directions.